# <a> tag inside an <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `li` item, that has multiple things inside it. It will be a thumbnail and a short description, and an `a` tag inside the `li` that makes everything a link (thumbnail, white space and description) and inside the thumbnail will be a Facebook share icon that needs to click through to a share link.

But because it's all wrapped in an `a` tag, the `a` tag around the Facebook share icon kills the outer one...

Here's the html:

```
<li><a href="">
    <div class="image-thumbail>
        <div class="share-icons-thumb">
            <a href="fb.link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="twi.link"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="events-text">
    <h1>Event Name</h1>
    <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 28/03/2015 - 13:00</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed diam
    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut...</p>
    <br>
    <h3><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Location 2021</h3>
    </div>
</a>
</li>
```

I've also mocked up a quick example in an image:
[image: img]

So I want the red circle to take you to the FB share link, and everything else to take you to the outer `a` tag link..........

Is this possible?

Any ideas/help would be great, thanks!

Comment: a is an inline element div is a block element, you shouldn't put a block element inside an inline element.

Comment: this is not an ideal solution but you can use z-index on inner element to make it clickable.

Comment: you social share link must reside outside the wrapping `a` and then position them using css position within li as required.

Comment: Did these answers help you or answer your question? If not please let us know so we can help more. Otherwise, would you please mark the most helpful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Comment: @BitwiseCreative Hey sorry guys, as you kind of saw it was a messy concept and was scrapped! Thank you for your helpful and concise answer though!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for your upvote. To mark an answer as accepted, click the checkmark underneath the vote count next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of odd nesting in your example that will give you problems. I wasn't able to even get the main `a` element working. I would recommend adding an action button instead of having the entire "card" clickable. However, you could use JavaScript to handle the card click. This might help.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="image-thumbnail">
        <div class="share-icons-thumb">
            <a class="link-fb" href="http://example.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook">f</i></a>
            <a class="link-twitter" href="http://example.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter">t</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="events-text">
        <h1>Event Name</h1>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 28/03/2015 - 13:00</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed diam
            nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut...</p>
        <br />
        <h3><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Location 2021</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-thumbnail {
    background: aqua;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.card {
    font-size: smaller;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.share-icons-thumb {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.share-icons-thumb a {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.card').on('click', function() {
        window.location = 'http://google.com';
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a0fncyvs/

The script in the fiddle doesn't allow window.location calls, and I added click handlers for the FB and Twitter links just for show and so you wouldn't actually be redirected here.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have used in the past is to bring the inner <a> element forward in the stack order using a higher z-index than the outer <a> tag, eg. z-index: 2 This will make the inner tag selectable. For example add the following to your CSS and your original HTML will work as you expect.

```css
.share-icons-thumb a {
  z-index: 2;
  }
```

```html
<li><a href="">
                <div class="image-thumbail">
                    <div class="share-icons-thumb">
                        <a href="fb.link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="twi.link"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="events-text">
                <h1>Event Name</h1>
                <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 28/03/2015 - 13:00</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed diam
                nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut...</p>
                <br>
                <h3><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Location 2021</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
            </li>
```